# How to make algo to find duplicate objects in a collection in Java more efficient?

Tags: java, performance, arraylist, collections, duplicates

I have declared an object `PersonDetails` which has the following three attributes:

```
long id; 
String residence;
```

I then have an `ArrayList` of `PersonDetails` objects that are all populated:

```
List<PersonDetails> personDetailsList = new ArrayList<>();
```

I need to loop through this list to find out the duplicate `PersonDetails` by matching their `residence` attributes.

```
Id  |   Residence
 1  |     a       
 2  |     b      
 3  |     a       
 4  |     a       
 5  |     b       
 6  |     c     
 7  |     c      
 8  |     d
```

The code/algo I've created for accomplishing this is below and uses a nested `for loop`, which is really inefficient:

```
List<PersonDetails> personDetailsList = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i <= personDetailsList.size() - 1; i++) {

    long personId = personDetailsList.get(i)
            .getId();
    String personResidence = personDetailsList.get(i)
            .getResidence();

    for (int j = i + 1; j <= personDetailsList.size() - 1; j++) {
        if (personResidence.equals(personDetailsList.get(j).getResidence())) {
            count++;
        }
    }
}
```

Could anyone suggest a more time-efficient manner to solve this? I'm trying to think of a better way to optimise this, but would much appreciate a second pair of eyes. A nested for loop would be hell for a larger dataset.

Comment: Well you can use a map to store the first element with a unique attribute, and query the map at each element.

Comment: @Andy thanks for the headsup! I've edited my code accordingly, pardon my previous comment

Comment: If `isDuplicate` is supposed to be the `id` of the first `PersonDetails` object with that `residence` value, why is it a `String`, not an `int` or `Integer`?

Comment: You could apply a sort, then iterate once and react from one element to the next if it is a group change or not. Problem is, that the sort may mangle the order of the elements, if you insist that the first element `a0` of a group `a0,a1..an` in the original list is the one the `a1..an` point to after duplicate detection.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it with a single iteration over the `PersonDetails` list, remembering when you encountered the `residence` for the first time using a `Map<String, PersonDetails>`:

```
List<PersonDetails> personDetails = new ArrayList<>();
personDetails.add(new PersonDetails(1, "a"));
personDetails.add(new PersonDetails(2, "b"));
personDetails.add(new PersonDetails(3, "a"));
personDetails.add(new PersonDetails(4, "a"));

Map<String, PersonDetails> encountered = new HashMap<>();
for (PersonDetails pd : personDetails) {
  PersonDetails first = encountered.putIfAbsent(pd.residence, pd);
  if (first != null) {
    pd.isDuplicate = first.id;
    first.isDuplicate = first.id; // mark the first encountered as duplicate
  }
}
```

Comment: Edited my question, I need to check and find all duplicates available throughout the collection, not just the first. Thanks!

Comment: @Mack that's what the code does, have you tried running it?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick optimization based on your code:

```
    for(int i = 0; i <= personDetailsList.size()-2 ; i++ ) {

        PersonDetails personDetail = personDetailsList.get(i);
        long personId = personDetail.getId();
        String isDuplicate = personDetail.getIsDuplicate();

        if(isDuplicate == null) {
            bool matchFound = false; 
            String personResidence = personDetail.getResidence();

            for(int j = i+1 ; j <= personDetailsList.size()-1; j++) {
                if(personDetailsList.get(j).getIsDuplicate() == null && personResidence.equals(personDetailsList.get(j).getResidence())) {
                    personDetailsList.get(j).setIsDuplicate(String.valueOf(personId));
                    matchFound = true;
                }
            }

            if(matchFound){
                personDetail.setIsDuplicate(personId);
            }
        }
    }
```

This code skips personDetails that have already been marked as duplicate.
Also, in the initial for we skip the last element because it is covered in the second for.

Answer (score 0):

Your last edit added an important detail to your requirements:

> Only values with a count > 0 should have a value `isDuplicate` != `null`, that is either its own id (first occurrence found) or the one of the first occurrence found.

Which means maintaining a map of first matches for each `residence` found includes possible updates on those objects, too.

In the following example, it is done the classic Java way without any streams or Java 8 features:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<PersonDetails> personDetails = new ArrayList<>();
    personDetails.add(new PersonDetails(1, "a", null));
    personDetails.add(new PersonDetails(2, "b", null));
    personDetails.add(new PersonDetails(3, "a", null));
    personDetails.add(new PersonDetails(4, "a", null));
    personDetails.add(new PersonDetails(5, "b", null));
    personDetails.add(new PersonDetails(6, "c", null));
    personDetails.add(new PersonDetails(7, "c", null));
    personDetails.add(new PersonDetails(8, "d", null));

    // data structure that holds the PersonDetails with the first occurrence of a residence
    Map<String, PersonDetails> firstIdFoundPerResidence = new HashMap<>();

    for (PersonDetails pd : personDetails) {
        // check if the current PersonDetails was found before
        if (firstIdFoundPerResidence.containsKey(pd.getResidence())) {
            // if yes, take it
            PersonDetails first = firstIdFoundPerResidence.get(pd.getResidence());
            // mark it as duplicate of the first one found
            pd.setIsDuplicate(String.valueOf(first.getId()));
            // and mark the first one itself as a non-unique residence
            // (by setting its own id, for whatever reason)
            first.setIsDuplicate(String.valueOf(first.getId()));
        } else {
            // otherwise just add the PersonDetails as first occurrence
            firstIdFoundPerResidence.put(pd.getResidence(), pd);
        }
    }

    personDetails.forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

The result (with a suitable `toString()` method in `PersonDetails`) is this:

```
[1, a, 1]
[2, b, 2]
[3, a, 1]
[4, a, 1]
[5, b, 2]
[6, c, 6]
[7, c, 6]
[8, d, null]
```

which is nearly exactly the desired result you posted, where I suspect you to have made a typo for id 7: Should have a value `isDuplicate = 6` instead of `7` because it is a second occurrence of `"c"` but has its own id set there.